# log4j does not print debug messages to file

Tags: file, console, log4j

Here's my log4j.properties file:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d{MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss} - %m%n

# Direct log messages to file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.file.File=logs/log.txt
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='-'yyyy-MM-dd'.txt'
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d{MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss} - %m%n
```

Here's how I'm using the Logger object in my code:

```
private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
log.info("This is an info message");
log.debug("This is a debug message");
```

**Problem:** Only info messages get printed on both console and file, whereas I need only info messages on console and info and debug messages in file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding below line to my log4j.properties resolved the issue.

`log4j.logger.somePackage.MyClass = debug`